# Scheme How To Test 2 Conditions in one Clause?

Tags: scheme

I need to create a sub-function that will return me all the adjacent node, which I needed for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575891/question-on-scheme-with-best-first-search-algorithm) in Scheme. I'm new to scheme, not sure how I can combine two conditions into one test case ?

Basically my algorithm is to test if the node is on the edge or not. This case I use a 5x5 grid.

If both node is on the corner meaning both is equal to either 1 or 5, than I will have only 2 adjacent node.
If only one of the node is hit the edge, I will have 3 node return value. 
If no edge around the node, I will have 4 node return.

My problem is how can I put 2 test case in one clause ?

```
(define (neighbors l w)
  (if (= 1 l) and (= 1 w)
      (display l w))) --at top left corner
```

Here I want to evaluate if l and w are both equal to 1. Now this doesn't work because I can't use "and" "or" such keywords in the syntax nor I can use & or + to combine them. Any ideas ? Or I should do something else ?

Comment: Note that display do not take two integer arguments. To get the output you want, the code should be:
(display l) (display #\space) (display w)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
(define (neighbors l w)
  (if (and (= 1 l) (= 1 w))
     (display l w))) --at top left corner
```

Because when I look to [this](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_118) , it seems to work that way

Comment: right !! thanks! works and I should use the same for display as well

Answer (score 3):

*when* and *unless* are more convenient than *if*, when there is only one branch to the conditional:

```
(define (neighbors l w)
  (when (and (= 1 l) (= 1 w))
     (display l) 
     (display #\space) 
     (display w) 
     (newline)))
```

Note that *when*’s branch is an implicit *begin*, whereas *if* requires an explicit *begin* if either of its branches has more than one form.

Not all Schemes has *when* and *unless* predefined as they are not specified in R5RS. It's easy to define them as macros:

```
(define-syntax when
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ test expr1 expr2 ...)
      (if test
      (begin
        expr1
        expr2 ...)))))

(define-syntax unless
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ test expr1 expr2 ...)
     (if (not test)
     (begin
       expr1
       expr2 ...)))))
```

Comment: mm it seems to me that the "when" is an underfined reference identifier. It's not a native buildin scheme function in my library :(

Comment: @FS It is trivial to add "when" and "unless", if your Scheme do not have them. Please see the modified answer.