# Scheme How To Return Multiple Values?

Tags: scheme, return-value

I notice that almost all scheme functions can only return one list as output.

In the following, I would like to return multiple values of all the adjacent nodes of neighbors.

```
 (define (neighbors l w)
   (if (and (= 1 l) (= 1 w))
     (list (and (l (+ 1 w))) (and (+ 1 l) w)))) ; how to output 2 or more values?
```

In this case I'm first testing if the node is at corner, if so, return 2 values of the coordinates where (l and w+1), (l+1 and w) basically if I'm at (1,1) return me (1,2) and (2,1)

Same applies when the node has only 1 neighbor near the edge, in this case I will have 3 values.

When no edge is nearby I will have 4 return values.

I tried to use `cons, append, list, display, write` none of them seems working with additional values. I need this as a sub-function of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575891/question-on-scheme-with-best-first-search-algorithm).  How should I implement it so I could pass on the return value and use it recursively to return me all the adjacent nodes?

**Edit**: I found the answer: use the keyword "`values`" to return multiple values.  Example:

```
(define (store l w)
  (values (write l)
          (write w)
          (newline)
          (list (+ 1 w) l)
          (list w (+ 1 l))))
```

Comment: Did you know you can post an answer to your own question? (If you like getting points on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, didn't realize I can do that

Answer (score 12):

values, continuation passing style, and list are at least three ways of returning multiple values:

```
(import (rnrs))


; let-values + values
(define (foo1)
  (values 1 2 3))

(let-values (((a b c) (foo1)))
  (display (list a b c))
  (newline))

; cps
(define (foo2 k)
  (k 1 2 3))

(foo2 (lambda (a b c) 
        (display (list a b c))
        (newline)))

; list
(define (foo3)
  (list 1 2 3))
(let ((result (foo3)))
  (display result)
  (newline))
```

Comment: the problem is, the number of return values varies, so list is really the only viable option.

Answer (score 3):

The Guile implementation of Scheme has a `receive` syntax, which it says is "much more convenient" than `values`. I haven't used it yet, however, but this may be useful:

http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Multiple-Values.html

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pair of values in a cons cell:

```
(define (foo)
  (cons 'a 5))

(let* ((r (foo))
       (x (car r))
       (y (cdr r)))
  (display x) (display y) (newline))
```

You can generalise this to return multiple values in a list, too.

Comment: thanks I just found a better way, use "values" I can return any number of return values I want :)

(define (store l w)
  (values (write l)
         (write w)
         (newline)
         (list (+ 1 w) l)
         (list w (+ 1 l))))

Comment: And this doesn't `print` pretty well, especially if you store pairs or lists in you car/cdr.