# Why my merge sort implementation in Scheme is so slow?

Tags: performance, sorting, lisp, scheme, racket

I'm aware of [Racket's stdlib](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._sort%29%29), but I want to implement a sorting function by myself as an excercise. I decided to use merge sort algorithm as it is naturally defined in recursive terms. Pretty soon I've come up with working code, but it works *too slow*. It seems to me that the running time is exponential of the list size, though theoretically it should be `O(n·log n)`.

Here is my code:

```
#lang racket
```

(define (pair x y) (list x y))

(define (split input)
  (cond
    [(empty? input) (pair null null)]
    [(empty? (rest input)) (pair input null)]
    [else
     (let [(tail (cddr input))]
       (pair (cons (first input) (first (split tail)))
             (cons (second input) (second (split tail)))))]))

(define (merge input1 input2)
  (if (ormap empty? (list input1 input2))
      (append input1 input2)
      (if (< (first input1) (first input2))
          (cons (first input1) (merge (rest input1) input2))
          (cons (first input2) (merge input1 (rest input2))))))

(define (sort input)
  (cond
    [(empty? input) null]
    [(empty? (rest input)) input]
    [else
     (let [(halves (split input))]
       (merge (sort (first halves)) (sort (second halves))))]))

(define (sorted? input)
  (cond
    [(empty? input) #t]
    [(empty? (rest input)) #t]
    [else 
     (and (<= (first input) (second input))
          (sorted? (rest input)))]))

It seems that I use some "atomic" operation which doesn't run in constant time as I might think, however I can't figure out which. Sorting of 30 random items is instantaneous, 40 items are processed in a couple of seconds, 50 items take half a minute. So I wonder, where is the snag?

Comment: PS: Any remarks on style, unmet conventions, etc are welcome. I'm a newbie in Scheme and would appreciate that.

Comment: Style-wise, why are you writing a function `pair` that makes lists?  You might want to look at returning multiple values from a function (the `values` function and the `let-values` Racket form).

Comment: Thought about starting with sorting n/2 parts and keep on going merging upwards?.

Comment: @Jeremiah, thank you for noting that, I was a bit confused that `(cons list list)` doesn't `print` pretty well, so replaced the native pair with two-element list. Now in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577279/scheme-how-to-return-multiple-values) there are some nice ways to return multiple results; `values` being amongst them.

Comment: @Zimbabao, essentially, this is the way how it works. There indeed happens a bit of reordering between the approaches, but I don't think it matters in the performance sense. The memory footprints seems equal too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `split`, you are calling `(split tail)` twice rather than using `let` to run it once and store the result into a variable.  That is probably making `split` take exponential time.

Comment: I knew it was something easy. Now it sorts 100000 items within seconds. Thank you.