# How to Assign Mulitpule Caulated Value Into List in Scheme

Tags: scheme, return-value

Okay this is my 4th question today on Scheme, still pretty new to Scheme, as I needed for one of my sub-function [I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575891/question-on-scheme-with-best-first-search-algorithm) in the day.

Basically this will return me the difference of 2 lists. Say you've got `(1,5)` and `(5,1)` this function should return me 8. As that's the distance between `l` to `w`

Here is what I have. Note: if I change the (list (- (car l) (car w))) into (write ..... ) the function will work, but outputs 2 number which I have no idea how to use those number as inputs of my other function.

So I try to put it into list, but doesn't really work out, it returns me with no error but weird stuff

```
(define (difference l w) ; calc heuristic function estimation
    (if (> (car l) (car w))
        (list (- (car l) (car w)))
        (if (< (car l) (car w))
        (list (- (car w) (car l)))))
        (if (< (list-ref l 1) (list-ref w 1))
            (list (- (list-ref l 1) (list-ref w 1)))
            (if (> (list-ref l 1) (list-ref w 1))
                (list (- (list-ref w 1) (list-ref l 1)))))
   )
```

Here is the code returned me

```
> (difference '(9 1) '(3 1))
#<procedure:...0\assigment 2.ss:50:3>
```

Any ideas? try to use lambda end-up the same thing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what your function is trying to do.

Comment: basically I try to calculate the difference of 2 item from 2 list. Say I got 1 from my first item in list A and 2 from my first item in list B. I want to see which one is bigger first, and then do subtraction it will return me the difference of the 1st item of the list. Same thing with the second item of the list. 

Once i got both number I add them together I got the total difference, in my case the distance from A to B

Comment: So the answer to your last example would be 6?  ((9 - 3) + (1 -1)) = 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, there's a typo in your code...

```
(lits (- (car w) (car l)))))
```

should be...

```
(list (- (car w) (car l)))))
```

**EDIT**: Would something like this work?

```
(define (difference lst1 lst2) 
    (if (> (car lst1) (car lst2))
        (+ (- (car lst1) (car lst2)) (difference (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
        (+ (- (car lst2) (car lst1)) (difference (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))
)
```

Comment: oopz i was using write instead and it works fine, but I can't use the output into any input. No use for me to use write or display function. So i try to use cons, append, list none of them is working

Comment: the weird that I didn't use cdr is because car return me a number rather cdr return me one number of a list. Yea that's why i use the list-ref to make sure I can do the calculation

Comment: `car` returns the 'first' element of a list, which is just a number.  `cdr` returns the 'rest' of the list, which is a list of length one (think of pointers in C).  `(list-ref .. N)` returns the Nth element of the list, thus `(list-ref .. 1)` is actually `(car (cdr lst))`, or abbreviated to `(cadr lst)`.

If this worked for you, feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I just wrote something like this.  Here's my solution

```
(define (difference l1 l2)
  (apply + (map abs (map - l1 l2))))
```